# GeoServer Error while trying to start the service: java.security.PrivilegedActionException

Tags: geoserver, java

I installed Geoserver 2.22.0 on Windows 10 with JAVA SE 11.0.16.1

Everything went well during installation. Then, I started geoserver and I had the following errors in CMD:

```
    Welcome to GeoServer!

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16.1

Please wait while loading GeoServer...

2022-11-25 12:15:57.079:INFO::main: Logging initialized @533ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2022-11-25 12:15:57.282:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.48.v20220622; built: 2022-06-21T20:42:25.880Z; git: 6b67c5719d1f4371b33655ff2d047d24e171e49a; jvm 11.0.16.1+1-LTS-1
2022-11-25 12:15:57.298:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/] at interval 1
2022-11-25 12:15:58.391:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2022-11-25 12:15:58.438:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2022-11-25 12:15:58.438:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2022-11-25 12:15:58.438:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
12:15:59 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Logging policy: Log4J2
25 Nov. 12:15:59 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Log4j 2 configuration set to DEFAULT_LOGGING.xml
2022-11-25 12:15:59.703:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [gwc.config] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory 'C:\ProgramData\GeoServer\gwc'.
25 Nov. 12:16:01 WARN   [config.XMLConfiguration] - GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
25 Nov. 12:16:01 WARN   [config.XMLConfiguration] - Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loading catalog C:\ProgramData\GeoServer
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'dem'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'giant_polygon'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'grass'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poly_landmarks'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_streams'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'tiger_roads'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace 'ne'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'ne'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'coastline'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'countries'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'boundary_lines'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'countries_mapcolor9'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'populated_places'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde'
25 Nov. 12:16:01 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'GeoPackageSample', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'coastlines', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'coastlines'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'countries', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'countries'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'boundary_lines', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'boundary_lines'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'populated_places', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'populated_places'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'world'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Arc_Sample'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Pk50095'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Img_Sample'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'roads', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'restricted'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'bugsites', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'archsites'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'streams'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'sfdem', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'giant_polygon'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poi', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poly_landmarks'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'taz_shapes', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_state_boundaries'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_water_bodies'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_roads', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'states_shapefile', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tiger-ny'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish'
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Read catalog in 1.344 s
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.layer] - Loaded 27 tile layers in 15.89 ms
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [storage.BlobStoreAggregator] - BlobStoreConfiguration gwc contained no blob store infos.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - Found system environment variableGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\ProgramData\GeoServer, using it as the default prefix.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--3ef31051:182c1e8b194:-8000', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-1c443fee:182c0f3f209:-7f98', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-1c443fee:182c0f3f209:-7f96', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-1c443fee:182c0f3f209:-7f97', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-1c443fee:182c0f3f209:-7f99', enabled
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.config] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory 'C:\ProgramData\GeoServer\gwc'.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [gwc.config] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory 'C:\ProgramData\GeoServer\gwc'.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas.
25 Nov. 12:16:02 CONFIG [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 27 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
25 Nov. 12:16:03 CONFIG [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
25 Nov. 12:16:04 WARN   [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi
25 Nov. 12:16:06 CONFIG [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
25 Nov. 12:16:06 CONFIG [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
25 Nov. 12:16:06 CONFIG [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
25 Nov. 12:16:06 CONFIG [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
2022-11-25 12:16:06.749:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5c7933ad{GeoServer,/geoserver,file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Program Files\GeoServer\webapps\geoserver}
2022-11-25 12:16:06.764:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main:
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by:
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
        ... 16 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
        ... 16 more

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Then when I type the url in browser, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Some one is already using port 8080 so you can't. Either change the port or kill the other thing.

Comment: I changed the port to 8081 and it worked!